# When I try enter date chosen by Jdatechooser it I get the Error "data exception: invalid datetime format"

Tags: eclipse, ms-access, jdbc, ucanaccess, jdatechooser

I want to input into my MS Access table the date that the user inputs using the Jdatechooser.

In Access I have set the Date/time column to 'short date', but any format I try won't work. Help!

```
try 
{
    Connection conn=DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:ucanaccess://E:\\testing.accdb");
    String sql="insert into Homework (Description,Subject_ID,Name,Due_Date) values (?,?,?,?) ";
    PreparedStatement pst=conn.prepareStatement(sql);
    pst.setString(1, textFieldDes.getText());
    pst.setString(2, textFieldID.getText());
    pst.setString(3, textFieldName.getText());
    SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("MM-dd-yyyy");
    String date= sdf.format(dateChooser.getDate());
    pst.setString(4,date);
    pst.executeUpdate();
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Data Saved");
    pst.close();
} 
catch (Exception e) 
{
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A date value carries no format. Try inserting the true date value *as is*:

```
pst.setDate(4, dateChooser.getDate());
```

Comment: It is unlikely that `dateChooser.getDate()` returns a `java.sql.Date`, possibly `new java.sql.Date(dateChooser.getDate().getTime())` will work.

Comment: @MarkRotteveel: You are right. I located a duplicate. Thanks.